# Why does this ultrafilter “filter out small sets”?

Tags: set-theory, filters

[This text](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emorrow/336_15/papers/gianni.pdf) defines an equivalence relation $\equiv$ as follows:

> Let $(r_n)$ and $(s_n)$ be infinite real valued sequences in $\Bbb{R^N}$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an ultrafilter on $\Bbb{R^N}$. $$(r_n)\equiv(s_n)\iff\{n\in\Bbb{N}:r_n=s_n\}\in\mathcal{F}$$Where equality of indexed terms is defined by real number equality.

They verbally describe this as two infinite sequences are equivalent if and only if they differ in finitely many places; it sieves out the “smaller” sets, as the article says. My question:

Suppose $A=\{n\in\Bbb{N}:r_n=s_n\}\in\mathcal{F}$. I define $X$ to be the power set of $\Bbb{R^N}$. Then we know $X-A\notin\mathcal{F}$. $X-A$ contains all members of the power set other than $A$ and its supersets. The article uses any arbitrary ultrafilter to define equivalence; therefore, they assume that any ultrafilter from $X$ must contain all possible infinite sequences of naturals, and any such $A\in\mathcal{F}$ is such that any sequence of naturals disjoint from $A$ is necessarily finite (trivially not in $\mathcal{F}$ as it wouldn’t be in $X$ either). Why? They are in fact asserting that it follows from the definition of an ultrafilter that if you have a “smaller” infinite sequence of naturals $B$ such that the set of all naturals not in $B$, let me call it $C$, is also infinite (I will take for sake of example $B$ as the sequence of all evens and $C$ as the sequence of all odds) then $B,C\notin\mathcal{F}$. How does this follow from the definition of ultrafilter? Let $B$ be in $\mathcal{F}$; $X-B\supset C\notin\mathcal{F}$. The article assumes $X-B\notin\mathcal{F}$ is somehow a contradiction... why?

Comment: I think you're confusing a few things. You seem to misread the quantifier on the ultrafilters; and you are confusing the intuitive idea of "filter out small sets" with the formal definition. In addition to that, if $\cal F$ is the ultrafilter, then it contains sets of natural numbers and not the power set of $\Bbb{R^N}$.

Comment: See (among other links) the following questions and their answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022022/intuition-about-filters https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312282/intuition-behind-filter-on-a-set https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816362/meaning-behind-filter-in-set-theory

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for those links. Is it the case that an ultrafilter on $\Bbb{R^N}$ necessarily only contains cofinite sequences? This doesn’t really make sense to me, since all elements of $\Bbb{R^N}$ are infinite. The article suggests that for any arbitrary $\cal F$ on $\Bbb{R^N}$, $A\in F$ implies that $\Bbb{N}-A$ is a finite set… why?

Comment: (1) The ultrafilter is on $\Bbb N$. (2) No. If it is free it will contain only infinite sets, but certainly it will contain either the set of all even or the set of all odds (but definitely not both). (3) Taking a quick look at the text, there seem to be some typos and and it seems to be an undergraduate thesis; without trying to offend anyone, perhaps it's better to learn a subject from a more experienced source.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Aha! I see. They annoyingly did not define that $\mathcal{F}$ was, and from context I assumed it was an ultrafilter on $\Bbb{R^N}$; thank you for clarifying that they meant it was on $\Bbb{N}$ and for noting the quality of the text. I had noticed the typos, and had thought the absence of definitions in places a bit odd, but trusted it nonetheless since I am not even at undergraduate level myself!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Doesn’t the presence of one of the evens or odds in $\cal F$ completely negate their assertion that $r\equiv s$ if they differ in only finitely many places? I say that because if you had $r_n=s_n$ whenever $n$ is odd, then they wouldn’t be equivalent by their verbal definition but they *would* be equivalent by their formal definition (assuming the odds is the one present in $\cal F$ - replace odd with even if necessary)

Comment: By checking other pdfs it seems that this is the standard way of defining an equivalence relation on $\Bbb{R^N}$ for the purpose of hyperreal construction: it seems then that we can define two hyperreals as equivalent even if they differ in infinitely many places, since there can exist sequences $(r_n)$ and $(s_n)$ such that $\{n\in\Bbb{N}:r_n=s_n\}\in\cal F$ but $\{n\in\Bbb{N}:r_n\neq s_n\}$ is an infinite set, if $r_n$ and $s_n$ are equal at $n$ odd (or even). Is this correct? Thank you for your time so far @AsafKaragila

Comment: No, two hyperreals are equal if they agree on a large set of indices, where "large set" depends on your ultrafilter. You can argue that equality should be independent of the ultrafilter itself, which is how we get "all but finitely many". But that's not the point. Again, let me ***very*** strongly recommend that you find a source written by someone more experienced with both the hyperreal construction *and* writing expositions.